# Pip + WSGI import errors

Tags: python, django, wsgi, virtualenv, pip

when i deploy my apps that worked fine using the django test server I usually get errors for every package I installed using pip install -e ....#egg=foo. I usually do this using virtualenv, which placed the files into env/src/foo and places another file into python/site-packages (this is an example of django-css):

django-css.egg-link, which contains the following lines:

```
/home/pinax-0.7.1/src/django-css
.
```

how do i tell wsgi that it should follow those links, or am I doing something wrong altogether.

thanks,
Philipp Wassibauer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what my WSGI script for Django in a virtualenv looks like:

```
import os
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'myproject.settings'

import site
site.addsitedir('/path/to/virtualenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages')

from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler
application = WSGIHandler()
```

The key bit is `site.addsitedir(...)`, which adds the contents of any `*.pth` files in the specified directory to `sys.path`.  In this case, it's the `easy-install.pth` file that Python needs help finding.

Comment: thanks...that worked. i knew it was just something small and easy i was missing.

Comment: +1. The .egg-link files are not related to importing, they are just metadata for setuptools to remember where the code is located. The import-related magic happens in easy-install.pth.

Answer (score 0):

The modwsgi documentation has notes on [how to use virtualenv](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/VirtualEnvironments). It is usually as simple as modifying your `django.wsgi` (or whatever you call it) file so that it adds the virtualenv environment to modwsgi's path.

[This link](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2009/05/notes-using-pip-and-virtualenv-django/) has some additional, distilled, notes on using pip/virtualenv/modwsgi.